# Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/: when creating condas environment from file

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, anaconda3, absl-py

I am trying to create an anacondas environment from a yml file I have, I have installed anacondas, have added

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

All to my path directory, still getting the same problem:

```
Pip subprocess output:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/absl-py/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement absl-py==1.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for absl-py==1.0.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main.py", line 80, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_create.py", line 141, in execute
    result[installer_type] = installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\installers\pip.py", line 70, in install
    return _pip_install_via_requirements(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\installers\pip.py", line 53, in _pip_install_via_requirements
    stdout, stderr = pip_subprocess(pip_cmd, prefix, cwd=pip_workdir)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\pip_util.py", line 41, in pip_subprocess
    raise CondaEnvException("Pip failed")
conda_env.exceptions.CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

It looks like it's trying to point to "https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/:" instead of "https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/" but I'm not sure if that's perfectly fine and there's just a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing anaconda?

Comment: @VaiTon Yes, multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution by copying the `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` files from the `Anaconda3\Library\bin` location to the `Anaconda3\envs\<myenv>\DLLs` folder. Seems like a poor fix, yet after hours of looking this was the only thing I could find that fixed the issue.